# Enameled Silver Wire?

Tags: wire, insulation, copper

I like to use enameled copper wire where rubbery insulation would be a pain.

Recently I embarked on an electronics project with some lights that would look a lot better if the wires were silver color instead of copper or red enamel.

I’ve seen ‘fairy lights’ all over amazon which feature several small LEDs in parallel across what appears to be enameled silver-looking wire. I could not find reels of this wire anywhere online, however.

Do these ‘fairy lights’ use plated copper wire that then gets enameled? Also, where can I get ahold of some?

I imagine it must be plated, as much of the insulated wire I have in the shop looks silvery when stripped, but the cross-section is distinctly copper.

**Update:**

Here is a close-up of the "fairy lights" from Amazon:

[image: Fairy Lights]

Even more zoomed-in, the insulation is barely visible:

[image: Fairy Lights Closeup]

**Update 2:**

The wire is not magnetic in the slightest. I took a long piece of it and slowly moved a powerful magnet near the end. No movement at all.

**Update 3:**

Here is a close-up of the cut cross-section. It is most definitely a copper variant core. I could do a resistivity test and break out my calipers to further test my hypothesis, but this seems unnecessary.

[image: Copper Cross Section]

Comment: I've seen someone ask this before for the exact same reason and there were no satisfactory answers. I think we reached the consensus that if it did exist, it was tin and definitely not silver, and that there is no functional reason to plate enameled wire and so it's really difficult to find, if it exists at all.

Comment: That looks custom. I've never seen enameled wire where the enamel bridges two conductors to form a pair before. The fact that you can actually see the insulation thickness in the photo makes it seem like it is some other form of insulation other than the enamel used for magnet wire. Just to confirm: You actually do have to scrape it off with a knife right?

Comment: @DKNguyen A knife must be used. The insulation is very fine. I imagine its polyurethane.

Comment: Well now we know for sure such a thing exists I guess.

Comment: @DKNguyen 'bonded bifilar magnet wire' is the term e.g. https://mwswire.com/specialty-wire/multifilar-magnet-wire/

Comment: @PeteKirkham Good to know. I still can't find any type of tin plated magnet wire...or steel magnet wire...BUT aluminum magnet wire is fairly easy to find. So maybe that's what you need. Though I doubt you will find bonded bifilar aluminum magnet wire unless you go out of your way to order a spool. You will need special flux to solder.

Comment: @PeteKirkham please see the images. The wire I am looking for is NOT bonded. It is two separate strands that have been placed close together. The bonded wire is a step in the right direction nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

If it looks silvery, it most likely is tinned copper wire, that is much cheaper than silver.

Insulation could be transparent PVC or transparent enamel, but I've never seen the latter. Try searching for "tinned wire transparent insulation".

[image]

Comment: Pointing out that it is likely tin and not silver is very useful (also mentioned by @DKNguyen). However, the wire pictured has insulation that is too thick. Lemme add a microscope image I took to the OP.

Comment: For the really cheap fairy lights though, those wires are probably iron or a mild steel. Much cheaper still, and the extra resistance doesn't really matter too much.

Comment: You can check the wire with a magnet. If it sticks, then it's probably steel wire plated with nickel/tin to make it solderable.

Comment: @peufeu That would make a lot more sense than plating copper wire and enameling it.

Comment: The insulation is usually silicone or PVC on these lights